# Transfroming ArcGIS Model into QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, modelbuilder

I have a model builder and it has proved to generate some results. I want to transform this model builder into QGIS Plugin, based on this [Converting Model in Plug-in in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337702/converting-model-in-plug-in-in-qgis).

I have followed the instruction such as:
(a) Exporting my model builder into Python Script
(b) creating the empty plugin (altwater_ev) using Plugin Builder, but I have a different 'basic files' of python file resulted in my plugin directory as shown here:

[image]

I hope I can build a plugin with the same interface with what the model builder appearance like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a limited number of python files (5). Try each? Altwater_ev would be my guess.

Comment: Then what should I do with my altwater_ev python file?how do I can copy the exported script from my model builder? Thank you