# Converting a Model Designed in Graphical Modeler into a Plugin with none/minimal coding

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have created a tool to predict wetlands on graphical modeler and I would like to create a plugin so I can distribute this tool as I think it would be very useful to others. Unfortunately, I do not know any coding (it's a limitation I know), and everything I researched is over my head. Is there a route I can take where I can just simply convert my modeler into a plug in?

I am using QGIS 3.10.2 and the model uses SAGA tools, raster calculator and the Raster Projection tool.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I am using QGIS 3.10.2. The model uses SAGA tools, rater calculator and the Raster Projection tool.

Comment: Have you looked at the answer to [Converting Model in Plug-in in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/342325/63384)? Also, [Creating QGIS Plugin starting from Graphical Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373908/creating-qgis-plugin-starting-from-graphical-modeler?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I have but I find this all so confusing as this is essentially a completely foreign language to me. I guess I will have to bite the bullet if there are no other easier ways to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way. The plugin is built using python, and thus you need to convert the graphical model into a python script and then build your plugin using PyQt5 which is another python module.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have some learning to do!